# Does matlab have nested polynomial evaluation function (horners algorithm)

Tags: matlab

I have been doing some work with polynomials recently evaluating them in basic form which I think may be inefficient and numerically unstable. I came across Horner's algorithm which I believe is a superior method to what I am currently doing. I was going to code it myself, but I thought I would ask here first if Matlab has any inbuilt function to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab uses Horner's algorithm to evaluate polynomials in [POLYVAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/polyval.html) (the algorithm is implemented as a digital filter for reasons speed in case the polynomial is evaluated for scalar input, see [this Mathworks blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/07/08/a-brief-history-of-polyval/) - thanks, Ramashalanka!).

The polynomial 4x^3+3 is represented as `[4 0 3]`, and can be evaluated for a value (or an array of values) of x like so:

```
polyval([4 0 3],1)
ans =
   7
```

Comment: @bazz: In some cases `polyval` uses a digital filter instead of Horner's method (`edit polyval` to see when), but see http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/07/08/a-brief-history-of-polyval/ for explanation of the equivalence.

Comment: @Ramashalanka: I thought I didn't need to be that specific (I did, in fact, `edit polyval`). Thanks for the link, though.

Comment: I knew you'd know. I just commented for completeness, since it was going to be part of my answer, before you bet me by a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had a feeling that Matlab would have something built in to do it.